# How to achieve a metro style in web

Tags: css, microsoft-metro, metro-ui-css

I'm not really a designer so I used css framework. And I find [MetroUI V3](http://metroui.org.ua/) (I love metro style) a great tool but I can only follow their templates or examples shown and apply it to my project. Im not that really creative.

And somehow, I want to mimic this design (see attached) because I want to display a collection of items, but since I don't have any images, I want to use tiles that could fit in and only put initials and some details on the side.

Can this be done using [Metro UI V3](http://metroui.org.ua/)?

This image is not mine. [reference](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/29400)
[image: Reference for list]

What I have so far. (I know, its not that much) I want to show more details in the list though.

[image]

Any suggestion for the design would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve that easily by using WinJS, Read more about it: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/winjs

And you can try it and play with it by: http://try.buildwinjs.com/playground/

You can select `Grouped GridLayout` to see the list, it has a lot of metro styled components..

Comment: Thank you so much. Great reference indeed. Do you have any tips on building metro style web app? A library perhaps? :)

Comment: More library perhaps?*

Comment: I have tried WinJS and it's doing great.. metro ui could help also :)

Comment: Do you recommend using WinJS today?